# How to get a indicator matrix that indicates the first occurrence within a group

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a DataFrame like so

```
x = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(start="2017-1-1", end="2017-1-13"), 
columns="a b c".split())
x.ix[0:2, "a"] = 1
x.ix[5:10, "a"] = 1
x.ix[9:12, "b"] = 1
x.ix[1:3, "c"] = 1
x.ix[5, "c"] = 1

    a   b   c
2017-01-01  1   NaN NaN
2017-01-02  1   NaN 1
2017-01-03  NaN NaN 1
2017-01-04  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-05  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-06  1   NaN 1
2017-01-07  1   NaN NaN
2017-01-08  1   NaN NaN
2017-01-09  1   NaN NaN
2017-01-10  1   1   NaN
2017-01-11  NaN 1   NaN
2017-01-12  NaN 1   NaN
2017-01-13  NaN NaN NaN
```

The result should be

```
a   b   c
2017-01-01  1   NaN NaN
2017-01-02  NaN NaN 1
2017-01-03  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-04  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-05  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-06  1   NaN 1
2017-01-07  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-08  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-09  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-10  NaN 1   NaN
2017-01-11  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-12  NaN NaN NaN
2017-01-13  NaN NaN NaN
```

The above desired output is generated as follows:

```
y = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range(start="2017-1-1", end="2017-1-13"), 
columns="a b c".split())
y.ix[0, "a"] = 1
y.ix[5, "a"] = 1
y.ix[9, "b"] = 1
y.ix[1, "c"] = 1
y.ix[5, "c"] = 1
```

Hope I make myself clear enough by the example.

Comment: Are there only two possible values, 1 and np.nan, or do you need to separate [1,1,2,2,np.nan] into [1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan] or [1, np.nan, np.nan., np.nan, np.nan] or something?

Comment: @DSM Yes, you can assume there is only 1 and np.nan.

Comment: @DSM Great solution that you provided! As a matter of fact, the matrix has values of -1 too. Your solution provided no longer works. But Great solution otherwise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try my best to understand what you need ..

```
ids=x.apply(lambda y : y.groupby(y.isnull().diff().cumsum().fillna(0)).idxmax()).stack()
y.combine_first(pd.crosstab(ids,ids.index.get_level_values(1)).replace(0,np.nan))

Out[49]: 
col_0         a    b    c
2017-01-01  1.0  NaN  NaN
2017-01-02  NaN  NaN  1.0
2017-01-03  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-04  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-05  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-06  1.0  NaN  1.0
2017-01-07  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-08  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-09  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-10  NaN  1.0  NaN
2017-01-11  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-12  NaN  NaN  NaN
2017-01-13  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It's almost there except that in my question, the y I generated is just for demonstration purpose. I shouldn't even bother to post code for generating y. I will modify my question.

Comment: @zsljulius we can still using recreate the data frame here, I think construction method always better :-)

Comment: @zsljulius if you have any question let me know

Comment: This solution works, and I do remember something along the line of using diff and cumsum to get the grouping. The only problem left is speed. The matrix I am dealing with is a lot larger than this toy example. Are there any more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: @zsljulius check the DSM's answer

Comment: Unfortunately, DSM's great solution works when the values are confined to be 1 and np.nan. So I guess the only route is to improve the efficiency of your solution

Comment: @zsljulius maybe you can go check the `np.vectorize`